# QnA Maker Confidence Score varies when imported the existing Knowledge Base

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have exported a QnA Maker Knowledge Base and imported the same in another QnA Maker KB. The confidence score of the utterances increased in the newly added KB. This change in confidence score is impacting the responses. The questions that are working earlier are not giving the expected responses in the new KB. I have done this using export/import option provided in QnA Maker. I am unable to figure out why the confidence scores are getting changed. can anyone help on this?

Comment: When was your old KB created?

Comment: @NicolasR Old KB created on September 14th, 2018

Comment: Ok so no impact from an "old" QnA Maker generation (before being GA)

Answer (score 0):

There is no static set of confidence scores. Confidence scores are generated dynamically for every utterance every time you call the API, which is non-deterministic by nature. Try training your QnAMaker app and see if it improves.